# Multiple Sorted Output in spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

i am trying to figure out multiple sorted output using datasets in spark

Input :-

city1 A1

city2 A2

City1 C1

city2 B2

city1 B1

city2 C2

i want output to be first sorted on basis of both the columns and then store each sorted output in individual file

output:-

File1:

city1 A1

city1 B1

city1 c1

similarly file2 will contain the data of c2

Comment: You can actually partition by city column and save them.

Comment: You can use groupByKey API and after getting the JavaPairRDD, sort the values and write the same in different partitions.

Comment: i want output to be sorted i.e file1 must contain city1 data and file2 must contains city2 data

Comment: `yourDataset.save().mode(...).parquet().partitionedBy("city")`;

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov that worked, how to do it in RDD?

Comment: @rushikeshjachak there is no simple way to do the same with RDD, so you can convert RDD to DF and then use the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way is to use `partitonBy`. The following code (in Scala) will produce a folder for each city with the required data.

```
val df = List(
  ("city1","A1"), 
  ("city2","A2"), 
  ("city1","C1"), 
  ("city2","B2"),
  ("city1","B1"),
  ("city2","C2"))
  .toDF("city","val")

df.sort("city", "val")
  .withColumn("city-part",col("city"))
  .coalesce(1)
  .write
  .partitionBy("city-part")
  .format("csv")
  .save("/output-path")
```

Note, that in order to have "city" column inside the output file, we add another column (city-part) with the same value to the data frame and use it for partitioning.

Comment: it worked but one question
why does sort create multiple partitions(thats why we used here coalesce) because when i removed that it created n files (n=input)

Comment: You have multiple files per partition not because of the sorting (you will have them also without it) but because of the way Spark works - it distributes the input between the executors and each executer writes the produced output to the separate file. If you need a single file per partition you can use `coalesce` or `repartition`.

Comment: yeah exaclty i just figured it out and came up with an alternative
dataset.repartition(col1).sortWithinPartitions(col2).write().csv(path)

Comment: the only difference between the two was that your solution created different directories while mine created all the part files in one single directory